# How to build a regex for a string that needs multiple validations

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create some regular expressions for a project that I'm currently developing.

I need to know how to create a regex that matches a string with the following pattern:

ABC Word Word

1. I need a 3 letter uppercase caps prefix at the start [A-Z]
2. All words that some next have to be spaced with a blank space and they need to start capitalized.
3. The string can not contain PM or MP as a secondary prefix. (ABC PM Paragraph) This applies for any position.

I've come up with this regex:

(^[A-Z]{3})(.* [A-Z][a-z]{1,})

It works correctly with a string like : "ABC Create User" but it also matches "ABCDE Create User" , "ABC CreAte User" , etc.

Comment: Both `Word`s cannot be equal to `MP` and `PM`, is that right? Or only the first `Word`? Are `ABC Word PM` and `ABC Word MPA` both valid?

Comment: Correct. PM or MP can not be inside the string. For example: ABC PM Word Word or ABC Word MP Word would be incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `.*` matches any 0 or more characters other than line break chars, as many as possible, and this pattern is rarely useful when validating strings.

You may use

```
^[A-Z]{3} (?!(?:MP|PM)\b)[A-Z][a-z]+ (?!(?:MP|PM)\b)[A-Z][a-z]+
```

Or, using a non-capturing group with a limiting quantifier:

```
^[A-Z]{3}(?: (?!(?:MP|PM)\b)[A-Z][a-z]+){2}
         ^^^                           ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/jkC3N7/1/) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/jkC3N7/2).

If you need to match two **or more** of such `Word`s, use

```
^[A-Z]{3}(?: (?!(?:MP|PM)\b)[A-Z][a-z]+){2,}
                                        ^^^^
```

The `(?!(?:MP|PM)\b)[A-Z][a-z]+` part does the following:

- `(?!(?:MP|PM)\b)` negative lookahead checks if the word is equal to `MP` or `PM`, and fails the match if the pattern matches
- `[A-Z][a-z]+` consumes an uppercase letter followed with 1+ lowercase ones.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast and accurate reply. Before marking this as the final answer i would like to point out that this regex only allows me to validate the prefix + two words. If i type ABC Generate Active Scheduler it only matches "ABC Generate Active" . Any thoughts?

Comment: @CarlosValls What do you need? The question is to match `ABC Word Word`, not `ABC Word Word Word`.

Comment: Your answer is totally accurate and correct. What I'm asking is if there is any way to validate n words after ABC that meets the criteria or i would have to specify how many words will the regex allow.

Comment: @CarlosValls See my update, I have shown how to match two or more of such words. *n words after ABC that meets the criteria* - if the `n` is a specific amount use `{2}`, `{3}`... `{n}`.